# Using BoxLayout to resize JPanels in GUI

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I currently have this code I am working with:

```
this.getContentPane().add(wwjPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        if (includeLayerPanel)
        {
            this.controlPanel = new JPanel();
            controlPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controlPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            this.layerPanel = new LayerPanel(this.getWwd());
            this.controlPanel.add(new FlatWorldPanel(this.getWwd()),Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(1000, 1000))); //This is the top pan
            this.controlPanel.add(this.getStates(), Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 100)));
            this.controlPanel.add(this.getPanelAlerts(), Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,100)));

            this.getContentPane().add(this.controlPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);//This is the whole panel on the left
        }
```

I am trying to resize the JPanels, called controlPanel here, to each have their own unique size in my GUI. I am new to building GUIs with java, and the majority of the code I have is pulled from another file. The code I am trying to incorporate are these new panels as described in my code, and trying to resize them. Is BoxLayout what I want to be using to get my desired effect?

Also, when I use the createRigidArea it seems to work, but if I continue to change the x and y values you pass to it nothing seems to happen. What I mean by this is, that I don't see any visual difference by changing the values, and I have used values ranging from 0-1000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.controlPanel.add(new FlatWorldPanel(this.getWwd()),Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(1000, 1000)));
```

The `Box.createRigidArea(...)` isn't doing anything. The second paramater of the add(...) method is a constraint to be used by the layout manager and a BoxLayout doesn't expect any constraint so it should be ignored.

If you want vertical space between the vertically stacked panels then you need to add it as a separate component and you would probably use `Box.createVerticalStrut()`:

```
this.controlPanel.add(new FlatWorldPanel(this.getWwd()));
this.controlPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut( 50 ));
```

The size of the `FlatWorldPanel`, is determined by the components you add to it.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: That makes sense, and I saw in documentation you linked to. But, having your perspective on it cleared it up.